# Стилизация input/textarea

Tags: html, css

Есть некий `input`со стилями `border-image` в виде подчеркивания.
Как добавить новый `input` и продолжить вводить текст дальше как только закончится ширина предыдущего инпута?
Либо это можно сделать как то по другому?

https://jsfiddle.net/hz7seapd/

Comment: Продемонстрируйте Ваши наработки и приведите пример того, что Вам надо, ибо сложно уловить что надо.

Comment: @Other да, конечно, секунду

Comment: @Other очень грубо набросал, но смысл один и тот же. Нужно при переполнении строки не что бы текст уезжал за пределы, а добавление новой строки с таким же оформлением

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не сразу уловил суть того, что надо сделать. Как вариант, можно пойти таким путём:

```js
var one = document.getElementById('one');
var two = document.getElementById('two');

one.onkeydown = function() {
  if(one.value.length == 25) {
    two.style.display = 'block';
    two.focus();
  }
}

two.onkeydown = function() {
  if(two.value.length == 0) {
    two.style.display = 'none';
    one.focus();
  }
}
```

```css
input {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  outline: none;
}

#two {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="one" maxlength="25" /><br />
<input type="text" id="two" maxlength="25" /><br />
```

То есть Вы создаёте n-ое количество инпутов с одинаковым maxlength и скрываете их все кроме первого. После ввода предельного числа символов в первый инпут автоматически открывается второй, и ввод продолжается туда (потом третий и т.д.) А если удалять символы бэкспейсом, то, соответственно, инпуты будут один за другим скрываться.

Проблема здесь в том, что нельзя будет дополнять текст в середине - только дописывать что-то в конце. Ну и не очень понятно, зачем Вам (кроме визуальной фишечки) нужно такое? )) Ведь содержимое инпутов, если его понадобится как-то использовать, придётся склеивать по кускам (оно не будет единым текстом, поскольку каждый инпут - это автономный элемент со своим содержимым).

Comment: Именно визуальная фишка и интересовала) Не чего поделать не могу, такое тз) Эти инпуты не будет использоваться более, чем написать/удалить в них текст. Спасибо вам большое, это то, что было нужно)

Comment: А можно ли это переделать немного по другому? Что бы не создавать и не скрывать инпуты, а что бы через createElement создавать новый и также его удалять и менять фокус? Спасибо

Comment: теоретически возможно - попробуйте ) вот здесь доп.инфа: https://learn.javascript.ru/modifying-document

Comment: Спасибо еще раз, почитаю)

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, тут без маленького js не обойтись. Вот так, например:

```
<div class="container">
  <form action="">
    <div class="form-item">
      <label for="">тестовый</label>
      <input type="text" onkeypress="this.style.width = ((this.value.length + 1) * 20 + 10) + 'px';">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hz7seapd/1/)

Comment: на вашем примере он просто растягивается. Может есть какой то другой способ это реализовать? Не через инпут? Гуглил про textarea, но это, как я понял, совершенно не подходит