# Перенос строки и стилизация input/textarea

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Добрый день. Хотел бы немного развить тему [Стилизация input/textarea](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/594649/%D0%A1%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-input-textarea). Хочу попробовать с textarea. Суть в том, чтобы делать автоматический перенос в textarea и сразу стилизовать строку. Насколько я понял, в textarea нет никакой стилизации строк, поэтому нашёл вот такой скрипт http://www.jacklmoore.com/autosize/ и подумал о том, чтобы написать скрипт, который будет вставлять блок с как бы стилизованной строкой под прозрачный textarea. Сам скрипт для textarea меняет именно высоту в инлайн стиле (допустим каждая строка 45px), то есть можно было бы добавлять/удалять блоки при изменении высоты. Интересует как реализовать срабатывание скрипта на каждые +-45px и сравнение с предыдущим показателем. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем перепробовав некоторые варианты, решил использовать что-то в таком роде, возможно не самый красивый вариант, но рабочий, кажется. Главное правильно разместить нужный background под textarea, чтобы одинаково смотрелся каждые 45px.

```
        var currentHeight = 90;
        var nextHeight = 0;

        $('#textarea').keyup(function(){
            nextHeight = $('#textarea').css('height').replace('px', '');
            if (nextHeight > currentHeight){
                $('#el').append('<div class="line">' + nextHeight + '</div>');
                currentHeight += 45;
            } else if(nextHeight < currentHeight){
                $('.line').last().remove();
                currentHeight -= 45;
            } 
        });

    });
```